# How to clone a repository in gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, git-clone

I have the following CI/CD

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    - ls -al
    - mkdir django_app
    - cd django_app
    - git clone git@gitlab.com:xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git .
```

It says

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:xxxxx/yyyyy.git .
Cloning into '.'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

How to clone the repository

Comment: do you want to clone the same repository, or another repository? do you use an own gitlab runner? or the shared ones? - why do you want to clone the other repository, what is your motivation behind that move?

Comment: I use shared one. Its another repository. But I have access to it. I need to build a docker image.

Comment: Why do you need the other repository to build a docker image? There are ways to add the host key ;) but I think the host key and the git checkout are a symptom and I would rather evaluate your root cause aka problem ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access multiple repositories in CI build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995578/how-to-access-multiple-repositories-in-ci-build)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ssh key with access to gitlab.com:xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git to your container before you try to clone.